# Зачем нужна закрывающая квадратная скобка в if-blocks?

Tags: bash

Если открывающаяся скобка является синонимом команды test, то у меня возникает вопрос - зачем нужна закрывающаяся скобка?

```
if [ $a -eq $b ]
```

В более поздних версиях bash поддерживается конструкция [[...]] (зарезервированное слово). В чем различия?

Почему при использовании [...] и нескольких условий (&&, ||) возникает ошибка, а при использовании конструкции [[...]] ошибки не возникает?

```
if [ $a -eq $b && $c -eq $d ] - ошибка
if [[ $a -eq $b && $c -eq $d ]] - не ошибка
```

**UPD:** используется интерпретатор #!/bin/bash.
Скрипты формата *.sh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

информация почерпнута из `man bash`.

1. начнём с терминологии.

   1. `[[` — это *compound command* (составная команда)
   2. `[` и `test` — это просто *builtin commands* (встроенные команды)
2. составная команда (их список далеко не ограничивается командой `[[`) характеризуется тем, что её аргументом может быть составное выражение, объединяющее выражения с помощью следующих операторов (перечислены в порядке приоритета вычисления):

   1. `( выражение )` — группировка выражений для изменения порядка вычислений/выполнения
   2. `! выражение` — «не»
   3. `выражение1 && выражение2` — «и»
   4. `выражение1 || выражение2` — «или»
3. команда `[` не является *именно синонимом* команды `test`. синтаксис их вызова несколько отличается, хотя функционально они идентичны:

   ```
   test выражение
   [ выражение ]
   ```
4. у встроенных команд `[` и `test` есть аналогичные, но чуть отличающиеся синтаксисом, операторы для группировки, отрицания, и логических операций «и/или»:

   1. `\( выражение \)` — группировка
   2. `! выражение` — «не» (тут синтаксис идентичен)
   3. `выражение1 -a выражение2` — «и»
   4. `выражение1 -o выражение2` — «или»

Comment: Большое Вам спасибо за объяснение!